# What is the voltage output from STM32 BluePill Digital I/O pins?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, stm32, logic-level

I am planning to use logic level MOSFET [IRL540](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91300/sihl540.pdf) as a replacement for my 5V 1 channel relay module to protect my Arduino pro micro from current requirements of the relay module. I would also like to use the same on STM32 Blue Pill, but I've just learnt it operates on 3.3V as opposed to Arduino's 5V. Can someone tell me whether the digital i/o on STM32 gives out 3.3V or 5V and whether it would be able to completely switch on IRL540 by below config?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The STM32F103 MCU has 3.3V I/O.

You might be able to still use it for slow switching if you use a 5V tolerant GPIO set to open-drain and an external pull-up resistor to 5V. For PWM I would suggest an external level converter or (better) a gate driver.